# signalr cross domain error in IE 11 but not in Chrome Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'

Tags: c#, sql-server, signalr, windows-authentication, impersonation

I have the following code in a SignalR method on a remote server:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=xxx.eee.eee.sss.com\sql01,1433;Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=SSPI";    
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
      //throws error when IE calls but not from chrome
      //Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.
      connection.Open(); 
      ...
    }
```

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections></configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>
```

IIS 7 Setup:

```
Authentication: Only two Enabled (everyone else disabled) 
  1.    ASP.NET Impersonation
  2.    Windows Authentication
```

C# SignalR code:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(mynamespace.Startup))]
namespace mynamespace {
  public class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
    app.Map("/signalr", map => {
        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration {
            // EnableJSONP = true
        };
        hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    });
    GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication();
    }
  }
}
```

The client JavaScript code:

```
function getData(caller, callback, cmdType, cmdText, args) {
    var connection = $.hubConnection(Globals.DatabaseLocation + Globals.RequestApplicationPath.replace('/', '') + "/");
    connection.logging = true;
    var Hub = connection.createHubProxy('SignalR');
    connection.start()
.done(function () {
    Hub.invoke("GetData", cmdType, cmdText, args)
            .done(processJSON)
        .fail(function (error) {/*...*/ });
})
.fail(function (error) {/*...*/ });
    function processJSON(message) {/*...*/ };
}
```

I have been stuck on this one for awhile any help would be greatly appreciated.

***Update:***

I did some more investigation: I had 3 other developers test in chrome, IE10, and IE11 and none of them get any errors. The authentication and impersonation setup outlined above works for all of them making cross domain calls and they get their data. I am the only one getting the error and I am only getting it in IE. Chrome works for me.

Comment: I'd expect that Chrome isn't using pass-through authentication while IE is. Does it work if you disable Windows Authentication in IIS?

Comment: The problem is your data source is either 1) not set up to allow Windows Authentication, or 2) your Windows User does not have a Login/User for SQL Server. whatever user is set for your AppPoolIdentity needs to have a login for SQL server and user rights for the database you're trying to access.